# Is the set of primes at even positions a Large Set?

Tags: real-analysis, analytic-number-theory

If we start numbering the prime numbers from 2, and we consider the subset of prime numbers at even positions, is it known is that set is large or not?

A subset of natural numbers is called "large" if the sum of reciprocals of its elements diverges. For example it is well known that the set of natural numbers and set of prime numbers are large sets. Surprisingly I could not find any reference to whether the set of primes at alternating positions is large or not.

I tried using Bertrands Postulate but failed. I intuitively believe the set primes at odd positions must be large as the but I cant seem to be able to prove it rigorously.

Any guidance/help would be appreciated. I am also looking for amateurish resources for studies on large subsets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This follows immediately from the fact that the set of primes is large. More generally, if $A=\{a_1<a_2<a_3<...\}$ is large, then so is $\{a_1<a_3<a_5<...\}$. The same holds for even positions (just think about $A\setminus\{a_1\}$) or indeed any arithmetic sequence of positions.

This is just because we have ${1\over a_{2n-1}}>{1\over a_{2n}}$. So we get $${1\over a_1}+\color{red}{1\over a_1}+{1\over a_3}+\color{red}{1\over a_3}+...>{1\over a_1}+\color{red}{1\over a_2}+{1\over a_3}+\color{red}{1\over a_4}+...$$ or more snappily $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} {2\over a_{2n-1}}>\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}{1\over a_n}.$$ If $A$ is large then the right hand side diverges, so the left hand side also diverges. Now just divide by $2$.

Comment: Thanks but what about the primes at even position?

Comment: @N.S.JOHN No different - just get rid of the first prime. This is what the "and so on" refers to - this trick works for **any arithmetic progression**. E.g. $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}{1\over a_{17n+307}}$$ diverges. I've edited to clarify this.

Comment: So can we generalise this fact about arithmetic progressions to all Large sets?

Comment: @N.S.JOHN Note that I wrote my answer in terms of arbitrary large sets, not primes specifically (see the sentence beginning "more generally"). It's fully general.

Answer (score 0):

You know that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac1{p_k}=\infty$. By Cauchy condensation, we have that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2^k}{p_{2^k}}=\infty$ as well. But we know that $$\frac{2^k}{p_{2^k}}=4\cdot 2^{k-2}\frac1{p_{2^k}}\le 4\sum\limits_{2^{k-1}< j \le 2^k\\ j\text{ even}}\frac1{p_{2j}}$$

And therefore $$\infty=\frac14\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2^k}{p_{2^k}}\le\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{p_{2k}}$$

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, invoking Cauchy condensation is massive overkill here - see my answer.

Comment: @NoahSchweber You are certainly right. It was really just the first idea that came to mind.